# How do I set a Background on a wpf form from Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, pack

```
this.Background =  
    new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Stream;component/images/empty.png")));
```

Doesn't work! I get an IOException, that says Cannot locate resource, My project's name is stream, even my assembly name and default name space...please help...

or if there's an alternative like converting the Bitmap Image to ImageSource please tell me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the **Build Action** on `empty.png` (right click the file in Solution Explorer and select Properties). It should be `Resource` (**not** `Embedded Resource`).